# In breadcrumbs, how to name a selected entry/location with no clear name?

Tags: best-practice, breadcrumbs

Imagine a breadcrumb like this:

Example: `Projects > "My Project" > Accounts > "Hans Muster" > Details`

*(If we omit "Details" (the current location) or not, is irrelevant.)*

These breadcrumbs include three static locations (`Projects`, `Accounts` and `Details`) and two 'named' locations (`"My Project"`, `"Hans Muster"`). Everything is fine so far, the breadcrumbs are pretty clear.

But what is the best approach, when such a 'named location' doesn't have a clear name?

Example:
`Projects > "My Project" > Logs > [Selected Log Entry] > Details`

Now, this is a bad example because Logs tend to have a clear date & time, so you could argue to use the timestamp as the name. I only used "Logs" as a clear example of something to bring my problem across. Imagine that there is no way to label the entry, at all - no date, no ID, just a bunch of numbers that would be meaningless out of context.

How does one best deal with this situation? What would be the best "Placeholder" for such unnamed entries?

Currently, I decided to just go with `Selection` since it's neutral enough and would even work for multiple selections if that ever becomes necessary, but I'm not entirely satisfied with that approach.

Example: `Project > "My Project" > Logs > Selection > Details`

**Besides just changing the label "Selection" to something else, like "Selected Entry" or whatever; are there any other approaches? What are the best practices here? If 'Selection' is just fine as solution, would there be a better word for a placeholder?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with "Selected Entry" is that if you send someone the link or forget what your selection was, there is no way to find out what you are looking at.

**Create an id for the selection**

would be my suggestion. If there is no meaningful meta-information, then just use the hash of the contents. I think something such as "Selection e73f1ece5087b8a5ae33998952202202" will be more useful than "Selection" (?).

Comment: I also suggest the ID, but undoubtedly, it should have less characters! `e73f1` or with text-overflow: `e73f1...`. Also, a # or any other indicator makes it more readable: `Logs > Log #e73f1... > Details`